# nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Hey guys,
I'm trying to have /blog redirecting to blog.mysubdomain.com
Here's the location part in my nginx conf :

```
location /blog {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect false;
  proxy_pass  http://blog.letitcast.com;
}
```

You can have a look here : http://letitcast.com/blog

It works but there's no CSS and I can't access /blog/wp-admin

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1 break;
```